# Can it be a bad idea to use the project dir as a template dir in Django?

Tags: django, templates

Don't get me wrong, I'm not talking about putting my HTML next to the settings.py file but rather add the project directory (which does contains the settings.py file) in the `TEMPLATE_DIR` list so I can call any template by naming it `'app/template/file.html'`.

I was just wondering why Django didn't come with template name space. It forces you either to:

1. create a template dir separate from all apps, then create a dir for each app and put your HTML in it.
2. create a template dir in each app dir and create another dir in it with the application name, then put the HTML in it.

This is less than ideal, since:

1. forces you to have your HTML outside your app. So much for being pluggable.
2. violates DRY by forcing you to create a redundant dir tree `project_dir/app_name/template/appname` otherwise if you have several templates named `'index.html`', you are screwed big time.

So is it a bad idea to just define the project dir as a template dir to call all template files `'app_name/template/file.html'`? If yes, why? How would you do it cleanly?

Answer (score 0):

I personally use `app_name/templates` for app related templates and `projects/templates` for global templates. Personally I find this useful as i really like loose coupling between my apps and my projects, so I tend to keep them detached.

However django gives you freedom of choice. If you feel fine with you're choice I don't see any problem at all.

Comment: And you use `app_directories` template loader I assume? The problem with this is, unless you put app's templates in `app_name/templates/app_name`, the template loader would consider the app's templates as being in the root. So, for example, to use a `my_app`'s `home.html` template, you'd have to refer it as `home.html` as oppose to `app_name/home.html`.

Comment: Correct. Name collisions would be easy without the `app/temp/app` scheme unless you are diligent about naming each of your app templates differently OR you can ensure your `generic.html` template exists in your app and will be loaded first. But no harm if that's how you roll! This is kinda like the strongly typed vs weakly arguments.

Comment: +1 to Nimmy Lebby. You risk name collision with this. @Yuji: you can be strict about the way you work, but sooner or later you will need to use so called "pluggable apps", and then problem begins.

Comment: Mistyped, sorry. I obviously meant the same layout that every app on the wild uses, so `app_name/template/app_name`. Is it supposed that I correct my answer following stackoverflow rules?

Answer (score 0):

You make an interesting argument against the way `app_directories` template loader works. Other than polluting the app's root directory with templates, I cannot think of something going wrong because of this.

Perhaps it'd be worth investigating in making your own template loader instead?

Comment: I thinking about it, but I feel it's overkill if something as simple using the root dir works. Now you are right, you must be sure that you don't end up with HTML mixing up with your Python files. However, I wonder how third party apps react in that case. And can it lead to security issues ?